# How to dynamically reset database config in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get sizes of the databases hosted on multiple servers. For Example, I have 2 databases on `Server A` and 3 databases on `Server B`.

I want to get sizes of all those databases from my Laravel application. Actually, I know how to `reset` the configuration. Here is the code I am using but it is only giving me the correct database size of the first database. Others are getting the size of `NULL` which is not correct because I know that the size of one of the databases on `Server B` is `0.6MB` because I've installed WordPress on it.

```
$databases = array();
foreach($servers as $server){
    // Setting Config
    Config::set('database.connections.mysqlClient.host',$server->ip);
    Config::set('database.connections.mysqlClient.password',$server->mysql_password);

    foreach($server->databases as $database){
        $database->size = DB::connection('mysqlClient')->select('SELECT Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "db_size"
            FROM   information_schema.tables 
            where table_schema = "'.$database->name.'";'
        )[0]->db_size;

        $databases[] = $database;
    }
}
```

As I've Configured credentials inside the loop, it should update the credentials or config for `mysqlClient` for each server. If it updates the config, I should get correct sizes for all the database which is not the case.

The script is not throwing any Exception. I am sure that there is something wrong with Config. It is because when I try to get sizes of all the database on the specific server, I get perfect results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untested as I don't have something like this currently setup, but I'm sure you need to purge the `DB` after a config swap:

```
$databases = array();
foreach($servers as $server){
    // Setting Config
    Config::set('database.connections.mysqlClient.host',$server->ip);
    Config::set('database.connections.mysqlClient.password',$server->mysql_password);

    foreach($server->databases as $database){
        DB::purge('mysqlClient'); // <-- Get rid of old connection
        $database->size = DB::connection('mysqlClient')->select('SELECT Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "db_size"
            FROM   information_schema.tables 
            where table_schema = "'.$database->name.'";'
        )[0]->db_size;

        $databases[] = $database;
    }
}
```

Edit: There is also `\DB::reconnect('mysqlClient');` but people have documented issues with it

Comment: Woohooo! Worked! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: I have been searching this for an hour. Thanks a lot.